# facebook javascript sdk login dialog flashes if already logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

the facebook javascript sdk login dialog just flashes (i.e shows then hides) if the user is already logged into FB.  Is there anyway to stop this from happening or is my code below not quite right?

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({ appId: 'XXXXXXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    };
    function connectToFB() {
        FB.login(function (r) { alert('connected'); }, { scope: 'user_photos' });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="connect" onclick="connectToFB();" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **check if the user is logged in** with `getLoginStatus()` first. Here is the official Facebook Documentatin: [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)